# Passing ajax return data varible to jquery selector

Tags: jquery

Below is the code append returned html via ajax,i want to convert return data to jquery selector so that i can passed the data varible like below

```
var $items = $('text').appendTo($( '#og-grid' ));

//load portfolio based on tags
$( "a.tag" ).click(function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault(); 
    url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $.get(url,function(data,status) {
        //console.log(data);      
        //var $items = $( $.parseHTML(data) ).appendTo($( '#og-grid' ));
        var $items = $(data).appendTo($( '#og-grid' ));
        //var $items $('<li> text </li>').appendTo($( '#og-grid' ));
        Grid.addItems($items);
    });
});
```

Comment: What `console.log(data);` prints? And what you want?

Comment: return html like <li><a href="">...</a></li>

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/add.html this is demo link, it add more items, i want to add more via ajax call, rather than string literals

Comment: But it throw  Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <li>

Comment: how are you sending the data parameter from server side?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, you need to make HTML at server end for example, if your are using PHP and the content comes from Database then you should return your data like,

```
<?php
   // mysql queries and get result
   // loop if data found
   echo '<li> <a>Something like that, with your images</a></li>;
?>
```